# How can I get a cleaner file information with print command?

Tags: bash, unix

I have this command to dump all java and xml files:

```
find . -name '*.*' -print -ls
```

I get the following output:

```
./auth-jaas/pom.xml
562949954141667    2 ----------   1 John ????????     1282 Feb 14  2011 ./auth-jaas/pom.xml
```

Is there a way to get something smaller like this:

```
1282 Feb 14  2011 ./auth-jaas/pom.xml
```

I'm only interested in file size and timestamp.

Comment: Do you have the `stat` command available?

Comment: I have it, never used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `du` instead:

```
$ du --time file
4   2013-03-20 19:49    file
```

With `find`:

```
$ find . -name 'file' -exec du --time {} +
```

Comment: can I dump the file size in bytes? pretty neat stuff

Comment: @code-gijoe it's displays in bytes by default. Read `man du` to see the different options.

Comment: problem is it removes the file extension so I cannot grep on the result by file extension

Comment: @code-gijoe `du` doesn't remove the file extension... file extension don't actually exist in Unix *(a period is just a valid filename character)*.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec stat -f "%10z %Sm %N" {} +
```

I got this as part of the output in one of my directories:

```
   534 Mar  2 20:17:16 2013 ./so.6964747
   835 Mar  2 20:17:16 2013 ./so.6965001
 25048 Jun 25 21:29:46 2012 ./so.8854855.sql
  7710 Feb 13 07:17:01 2013 ./sortAtt.c
  1565 Sep  4 19:15:30 2010 ./strandsort.c
  7224 Sep 22 13:42:17 2012 ./streplace.c
  3033 Jan 28 23:16:46 2013 ./substr.c
   139 Mar 20 12:48:24 2013 ./sum.sh
  6833 Sep 21 07:57:53 2012 ./timezeromoves.c
   614 Feb 21 09:23:00 2013 ./travAsm.c
   347 Feb 21 09:23:00 2013 ./traverse.c
  1277 Jul 26 09:30:12 2012 ./uint128.c
   793 Aug 19 00:47:48 2012 ./unwrap.c
  1906 Jul 28 08:41:22 2012 ./xxx.sql
  1904 Sep 22 21:30:09 2011 ./yyy.sql
```

Reading up on the options might tell you how to drop the time from the 'string format for the modification time' (`%Sm`).

Just for the record, this was using `/usr/bin/stat` on Mac OS X 10.7.5, not GNU [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).  You will need to scrutinize what's available there.

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec /usr/gnu/bin/stat --format "%s   %y   %N"
```

And the same part of the output was:

```
534   2013-03-02 20:17:16.000000000 -0800   ./so.6964747
835   2013-03-02 20:17:16.000000000 -0800   ./so.6965001
25048   2012-06-25 21:29:46.000000000 -0700   ./so.8854855.sql
7710   2013-02-13 07:17:01.000000000 -0800   ./sortAtt.c
1565   2010-09-04 19:15:30.000000000 -0700   ./strandsort.c
7224   2012-09-22 13:42:17.000000000 -0700   ./streplace.c
3033   2013-01-28 23:16:46.000000000 -0800   ./substr.c
139   2013-03-20 12:48:24.000000000 -0700   ./sum.sh
6833   2012-09-21 07:57:53.000000000 -0700   ./timezeromoves.c
614   2013-02-21 09:23:00.000000000 -0800   ./travAsm.c
347   2013-02-21 09:23:00.000000000 -0800   ./traverse.c
1277   2012-07-26 09:30:12.000000000 -0700   ./uint128.c
793   2012-08-19 00:47:48.000000000 -0700   ./unwrap.c
1906   2012-07-28 08:41:22.000000000 -0700   ./xxx.sql
1904   2011-09-22 21:30:09.000000000 -0700   ./yyy.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Linux-style `-printf` in your `find` command, use `%a` for access time, `%t` for mod-time (and uppercase variants for more specific formatting) and `%s` for file size in bytes.

Alternatively, pipe the output from `-ls` through `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say cut, but not knowing if they are tab or space separators:

```
find . -name '*.*' -print -ls |awk '{$0=substr($0,index($0,FS)+4);printf $0}'
```